# How can I set up logrotate to rotate logs hourly?

Tags: linux, logrotate

According the the Unix and Linux Administration Handbook and `man`, logrotate has options for `daily`, `weekly`, and `monthly`, but is there a way to add an `hourly` option?

[This blog post](http://packetcloud.net/index.php/making-logrotate-rotate-apache-logs-every-hour-or-2-or-3/) mentions you can set `size 1` and remove the time option (eg: `daily`) and then manually call `logrotate` with `cron` - I suppose something like

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/my-hourly-file
```

but is there a more elegant solution for rotating logs hourly?

Comment: Sure. What is your operating system, what version?

Comment: ubuntu 10.04 and 11

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Depending on your OS. Some (all?) Linux distributions have a directory `/etc/cron.hourly` where you can put cron jobs to be executed every hour.

Others have a directory `/etc/cron.d/`. There you can put cron-jobs that are to be executed as any special user with the usual cron-settings of a crontab entry (and you have to specify the username).

If you use either of these instead of the standard log rotatation script in `/etc/cron.daily/` you should copy that script there and `cp /dev/null` to the original position. Else it will be reactivated by a logrotate patch-update.

For proper hourly rotation, also take care that the `dateext` directive is *not* set. If so, by default the first rotated file will get the extension of the current date like YYYYMMDD. Then, the second time logrotate would get active within the same day, it simply skips the rotation even if the `size` threshold has exceeded.

The reason is that the new name of the file to get rotated already exists, and logrotate does not append the content to the existing old file.
For example on RHEL and CentOS, the `dateext` directive is given by default in `/etc/logrotate.conf`. After removing or commenting that line, the rotated files will simply get a running number as extension until reaching the `rotate` value. In this way, it's possible to perform multiple rotations a day.

Comment: Great, helped me a lot. To add for those who are looking for this, to disable dateext, add the tag "nodateext" in the config

Answer (score 14):

Just to add to Nils answer, if changing the location of the `logrotate` script on a Debian or Ubuntu box, it's probably safer to use `dpkg-divert` instead of just copying the file and copying `/dev/null` to the original position e.g.:

```
dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /etc/cron.hourly/logrotate /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

Comment: I didn't know about this and I've been using Ubuntu for years. Thank you. :)

Comment: Wouldn't `ln -s /etc/cron.daily/logrotate /etc/cron.hourly/logrotate` work?

Answer (score 3):

One other option would be adding the logrotate command into crontab list. Then it will execute for every hour.

```
crontab -e
```

add below line into crontab list

```
0 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/my-hourly-file
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone coming back to this. Logrotate now has hourly option. You will have to put the logrotate script to the hourly cron though as it is in daily by default. Don't forget to remove it from the daily cron as it will run 2x in the same hour every day once at 3am~. (default cron.daily time afai

https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate

Comment: With `hourly` chosen, `dateext` now may be set too.  By default, with `hourly`, `dateext` adds the two digit hour (from a 24-hour clock) at the end of the date suffix.  From the `logrotate` man page on `dateformat`:  "Specify the extension for dateext .... %Y %m %d %H %M %S %V and %s specifiers are allowed. The default value is -%Y%m%d except hourly, which uses -%Y%m%d%H ...."